# Counterintuitive memory allocation

Tags: memory, rust, memory-model

Created a small rust program to understand the memory allocation. Just wanted to understand if the data types use the memory area they are supposed to get allocated to.

```rust
fn main() {
    // stack
    let num: u8 = 89;
    // heap
    let boxed_num = Box::new(89);
    // stack
    let num2: u8 = 99;
    //heap
    let boxed_num2 = Box::new(99);
    // heap
    let s = String::from("hello");

    println!(
        "
        num:        {:p}
        boxed_num:  {:p}
        num2:       {:p}
        boxed_num2: {:p}
        string:     {:p}
        ",
        &num, &boxed_num, &num2, boxed_num2, &s
    );
}
```

I was expecting `num` and `num2` to get allocated on **stack**

And `boxed_num`, `boxed_num2` and `s` on **heap**

the program output was

```
        num:        0x7fff40d38def
        boxed_num:  0x7fff40d38df0
        num2:       0x7fff40d38dff
        boxed_num2: 0x55cf316c4af0
        string:     0x7fff40d38e08
```

But I was amazed when I checked the proc maps. It was

```
cat /proc/6182/maps
55cf316c4000-55cf316e5000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                          [heap]
7fff40d19000-7fff40d3b000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                          [stack]
```

How it could be possible? only boxed_num2 seems to be on **heap** and every other var goes to stack. Took multiple iterations. This pattern is consistent.

> Why only `boxed_num2` on heap?

> Why `boxed_num` and `s` on stack?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both `boxed_num`, `boxed_num2` and `s` are objects that live on the stack and point to data on the heap.

To get the heap part of `Box`/`String`, you need to call `Box::as_ref()` or `String::as_bytes()`.

The reason why `boxed_num2` was shown on the heap was that you didn't add a `&` to it, causing an automatic dereference to its heap value.
This is because `{:p}` expects a reference, and `boxed_num2` can implicitely be converted into its heap value reference.

Here you go:

```
fn main() {
    // stack
    let num: u8 = 89;
    // heap
    let boxed_num = Box::new(89);
    // stack
    let num2: u8 = 99;
    //heap
    let boxed_num2 = Box::new(99);
    // heap
    let s = String::from("hello");

    println!(
        "
        num:        {:p}
        boxed_num:  {:p}
        num2:       {:p}
        boxed_num2: {:p}
        string:     {:p}
        ",
        &num,
        boxed_num.as_ref(),
        &num2,
        boxed_num2.as_ref(),
        s.as_bytes(),
    );
}
```

```
        num:        0x7ffd1375d7cf
        boxed_num:  0x557006c71ad0
        num2:       0x7ffd1375d7df
        boxed_num2: 0x557006c71af0
        string:     0x557006c71b10
```

Comment: Note that you don't need `.as_ref()`, `println!` is smart enough for it.

Comment: Yah, I mentioned that in my answer. But just saying it doesn't make it clear why some of them need an `&` and some don't.

Comment: I consider `as_ref()` in non generic situations an antipattern, `&*` is better and less ambiguous.

Comment: Sure, I just wanted to write it down here to make it very explicit what is going on behind the scenes. Would you mind elaborating why you think that? 'is better and less ambiguous' is a very subjective claim.

Comment: @Finomnis any reference in rust book for the same?

Comment: @ShindeArjun probably this one: https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch15-00-smart-pointers.html